# How to cut off parts of text by an object in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

I'm new to Adobe Illustrator, and currently I'm trying to cut a letter off by an object. In the following I am going to explain what I mean:

- I have drawn a rectangle.
- I have written some text.
- I positioned the text over the rectangle, so that parts of the text are inside of the rectangle, parts of it are outside.

What I now want to achieve is to cut off every part of the text that is outside the rectangle.

Please note that I do not want to subtract the text from the rectangle - the text (at least the part which is inside) shall still be there.

How could I accomplish this task?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly; there are a few ways, and this is one:

Create text, create the rectangle. Then do the following: select both, go to `object` -> `clipping mask` -> `make`. It does not matter what the box looks like. This should give you the text that was "underneath" the box.

[image]

Comment: I agree about using a clipping mask.. but no need to outline text.

Comment: Ah! nice, @Scott curiously, I have not tried without :D

Comment: Basically a very nice solution, but this means that I have the rectangle on top of the text - I want it the other way round (text on top of rectangle). AFAICS this does not work using a clipping mask, does it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The rectangle "disappears" and you are left with only the bit of text. Why does the rectangle have to be behind the text?

Comment: The rectangle 'behind the text' is coloured? Just pop another coloured rectangle behind it.